# How to stop play sound by press button back or button home

Tags: android, audio

How to stop play sound by press button back or button home
Please Help me :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button play;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_play);
        final MediaPlayer mP = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.music);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mP.isPlaying()) {
            mP.pause();
            play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);

             } else {
             mP.start();
             play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);

              }



}

}

);

}}
```

Comment: you can pause that mediaplayer on onBackPressed() method.

Answer (score 1):

Pause media player in `onPause();` Method

```
  @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Hope It will work for you.
For more information Refer [MediaPlayer LifeCycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Answer (score 1):

to stop music player

```
 private void stopPlaying() {
            if (mp != null) {
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
                mp = null;
           }
        }
```

**to stop play sound by press button back or button home**

in Activity you need to stop music on `onDestroy` and `onBackPressed`

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    stopPlaying();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    stopPlaying();
}
```

Comment: Thanks you Adilhusen